# How to run pybench with Cython

Tags: python, benchmarking, cython

I just installed Python 2.7 on Windows 2008 server and have successfully executed the benchmark called PYBENCH.

Now, I installed Cython (over the existing installation of Python) and I want to run the same benchmark. My question is: How do I run the benchmark on Cython instead of Python?

Comment: You can't "run" a python file with cython. Cython converts them to C code which needs to be compiled then. After that you can import such a module in python to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need: **Cython, Python and a C compiler** and a "*file.py*"

Compile, link and run:

```
$ cython --embed file.py   # <- embed a main() function

$ gcc $CFLAGS -I/usr/include/python2.6 -o out_name file.c -lpython2.6 -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl

$ ./out_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Cython is not a replacement for Python.  It's a different language which is syntactically close to Python.  In general, it cannot run existing Python programs out of the box.

If you want a possibly faster replacement for Python, try PyPy.  Don't be confused about PyBench, though --- you'll see a huge speed-up (at least 1000x?), but this is due to the fact that PyPy optimizes away most of the benchmark, which doesn't do anything.  For more reasonable benchmarks see [http://speed.pypy.org/](http://speed.pypy.org).

Comment: For my project I need to use Cython, not interested PyPy. I need to run a .py file using Cython, how is running (which is the command) a .py file using Cython?

Comment: Cython does not run existing Python programs out of the box.